# html5 drag and drop dropzone dance

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am doing html drag and drop,while doing it I faced one issue, UI is dance. My code is simple while hovering drag and drop option I am appending the one extra dotted div,on hover out I am deleting the dotted div. while appending after appending not giving any issue, but before appending , UI is dancing. **I am not supposed to use jquery UI.**

I find out the problem, while creating the extra div ,drop hover has been moved, the extra div creating and deleting looping.

Is there any idea can some one give?

```
elem.addEventListener('dragover', this.handledragEnter.bind(this), false);
            elem.addEventListener('dragleave', this.handleddragleave.bind(this), false);

handledragEnter:function(e){
            if($('#dropZone').length == 0){
                //if($(e.srcElement).is(':last-child')){
                    if($(e.srcElement).hasClass('assignedListItem')){
                        $(e.srcElement).before('<div id="dropZone" style="border:1px solid red;width:100px;border-style: dotted;height:30px;"></div>');
                    }
                    else{
                        $(e.srcElement).closest('.assignedListItem').before('<div id="dropZone" style="border:1px solid red;width:100px;border-style: dotted;height:30px;"></div>');
                    }
                    if($("#dropZone").next().hasClass( "styleDragBorder" )){
                        $("#dropZone").next().hide();
                    }
               // }

            }


        },

handleddragleave:function(e){
            $("#dropZone").next().show();
            if($('#dropZone').length == 1){
                $('#dropZone').remove();
            }

        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not able to solve this, So I used [html5Sortable](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/). This is easy to use and solve the dance problem, and it requires only jquery. not jquery ui.